# WiFi dropping with channel switch and not reconnecting: how to debug

Tags: wi-fi, 9.0-pie, debug, router

Since a few days my new Samsung Galaxy A50 (running Pie build PPR1.180610.011.A505FNXXU1ASD6)  is dropping the WiFi connection to my router (Fr!tzBox 7940) for no clear reason.
I've been trying all the suggestions I found on the web:

1. Changing DNS/disabling PiHole (as I have/had one), as somebody with a Pihole experienced the same issue [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/202531/296373): didn't solve it.
2. Disabling IPv6 on the router: didn't solve it.
3. Using a static IP address for the device: didn't solve it.
4. Reset the network settings on the device: didn't solve it.
5. Factory reset the device... a lot of work... didn't solve it.

The funny thing is that the phone is the only device experiencing issues. We also have a Samsung Tab (gen1), Tab S3, S7, multiple HP laptops and a Tanix TX6 that experience no issues at all!
... I am expecting radio issues.

Every time this occurs, I need to disable and re-enable the Wifi of the A50 to get a connection again. Sometimes it even lists my router, but just doesn't (automatically) connect.
[image]
Sometimes it even lists no Wifi sources at all! Even though I should see the weak signal from the neighbors: it's quite busy here
[image]
Sometimes I don't even get the WiFi to enable!!

The logging apps I found don't tell me much. E.g. the app "WiFi monitor" logs this (translated):

```
2019-05-16 17:20:06 WiFi is switched on. WiFi network is connected: "FRITZ!Box 7490". RSSI: -52 dBm
2019-05-16 17:20:08 WiFi is switched on. WiFi network is connected: "FRITZ!Box 7490". RSSI: -48 dBm
2019-05-16 17:20:46 WiFi is switched on. Connecting to WiFi network…
2019-05-16 17:20:46 WiFi is switched on. No connected WiFi networks
[3 minuted later I find out and manually intervene]
2019-05-16 17:23:51 WiFi is switched on. No connected WiFi networks
2019-05-16 17:52:05 WiFi is being switched off
2019-05-16 17:52:05 WiFi is switched off
2019-05-16 17:52:08 WiFi is being switched on
2019-05-16 17:52:09 WiFi is switched on. No connected WiFi networks
2019-05-16 17:52:11 WiFi is switched on. Connecting to WiFi network…
2019-05-16 17:52:11 WiFi is switched on. WiFi network is connected: "FRITZ!Box 7490"
2019-05-16 17:52:11 WiFi is switched on. WiFi network is connected: "FRITZ!Box 7490". RSSI: -54 dBm
2019-05-16 17:52:12 WiFi is switched on. WiFi network is connected: "FRITZ!Box 7490". RSSI: -56 dBm
```

My router also has some logs indicating that in some cases it might be related to channel switching:

```
16.05.19 17:52:13 New wireless device registered itself (5 GHz), 433 Mbit/s, Galaxy-A50, IP 192.168.178.97, MAC [cut].
16.05.19 17:52:11 Wireless LAN device registered: Reactivating wireless LAN at full power (5 GHz).
16.05.19 17:25:57 Wireless auto channel: The channel settings (previously channel 52 (5 GHz)) were changed; now active on channel 36 (5 GHz).
16.05.19 17:25:51 Wireless auto channel: Current detection of the wireless LAN environment (5 GHz) in progress, in order to optimize the wireless channels in use; some wireless devices may be re-registered.
16.05.19 17:23:50 No more wireless LAN devices registered: Reducing power consumption (5 GHz).
16.05.19 17:20:52 Wireless device was deregistered (5 GHz), Galaxy-A50, IP 192.168.178.97, MAC [cut].
16.05.19 17:20:03 Reregistered wireless device (5 GHz): Automatic change of wireless band to improve data transmission, Galaxy-A50, IP 192.168.178.97, MAC [cut].
16.05.19 17:20:03 Wireless device registered (5 GHz), 433 Mbit/s, Galaxy-A50, IP 192.168.178.97, MAC [cut].
16.05.19 17:20:01 Wireless LAN device registered: Reactivating wireless LAN at full power (5 GHz).
16.05.19 17:19:58 Wireless device was deregistered (2,4 GHz), Galaxy-A50, IP 192.168.178.97, MAC [cut].
```

I'm trying to find a way for android to tell me *why* it is dropping the wifi and not reconnecting. Any tips?

Comment: Which Wifi 2.4GHz channel is used by your Fritz!Box? Which country you live in? Is the 5GHz network strong enough (the log shows your phone tries to use 5GHz) at all points you use the phone?

Comment: @Robert the box automatically switches channels, so there's no fixed 2.4GHz or 5GHz channel. As the picture second picture shows, the 5GHz is quite strong. Also, the phone does see the 2.4Ghz but simply doesn't automatically connect (even though it should). On other occasions it doesn't see radio sources at all, while they are there. It seems like the wifi radio SW "crashed" or so. I mean: even if the 5GHz is bad, it could switch to 2.4GHz right? It does so in other occasions. I want debug information from the wifi radio SW...